# How to query items based on permissions?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I would like to query for items that the Context user as *write* access to rather than read access.  ie, normally I would do something like this:

Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectItems("/sitecore/content/somepath/*");

...and that would return an Item[] array for all the those items the user has read access to.  Is there a mechanism for retrieving only the items the user has write access to?  Or am I going to have to just iterate through the items and check them individually?

How do I check if the context user has this permission for a given Item?

Comment: Hmmm... I guess the answer to the last part would be itemObject.Security.CanWrite(Sitecore.Context.User);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to "look" like you aren't iterating over the list, you can execute the security check inside a LINQ query.  Something like this:

```
var result = Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectItems("/sitecore/content/somepath/*").Where(x => x.Security.CanWrite(Sitecore.Context.User));
```

Comment: Good answer, I think this is about as simple as it could get.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have to deal with these individually as [Sitecore Query](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Using%20Sitecore%20Query/Sitecore%20Query%20Syntax.aspx) doesnt have any functions or attributes for it to check the security attributes of an item. (neither does Fast Query as far as I know).